# Reset MetaMask nonce

Tags: metamask, nonce

I am testing stuff on Ganache and am using Metamask to send transactions to simulate user behavior with the app. Now here's the issue. If I restart Ganache it resets all accounts (no problem with that). However, Metamask keeps the old transactions in it's memory and thinks the nonce of a new transaction is nonzero. That is not true.

If I want to fix this, I should delete all my accounts, which I am not going to do. There should be a default way of resetting nonces. I've tried reconnecting to the network, but it seems that it remembers that even "localhost:7545" will be the same network all the time, hence nonces never change.

Comment: Never mind, you can reset an account which is hidden in the "settings" menu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to this documentation, there is a reset button in Metamask.

https://metamask.helpscoutdocs.com/article/36-resetting-an-account

See also https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/3479

Comment: The way to fix incorrect nonces is now: Settings -> Advanced -> Reset Account