# Not able to successfully send Transactions via MetaMask on Firefox Browser

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, metamask

Does anybody help me figuring out why I am getting failed transaction here?What does this error means? Few days back,with the same line of code,I was able to successfully send transactions.

An update:

With same code and setup I am able to successfully send transactions via MetaMask on chrome browser with no issues.

But on Mozilla Firefox ,I am getting failed transactions. Seems like some issue with MetaMask compatibility with firefox? Attaching screenshot with this comment of mine is of Mozilla Browser issue.(Though couple of days back I was able to successfully send transactions on my firefox browser too)

Web3.js Version : "web3": 1.2.1
Truffle v5.0.30 
Please refer to the attached screenshots for issue.

[image][image]

Comment: If you have restarted ganache you need to reset Metamask https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/44311/reset-metamask-nonce.

Comment: I did not re-started Ganache.With same code and setup I am able to successfully send transactions via MetaMask on chrome browser.But on Mozilla Firefox ,I am getting failed transactions. Seems like some issue with MetaMask compatibility with firefox? (Though couple of days back I was able to successfully send transactions on my firefox browser too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was/is :

Everytime we Re-start ganache ,we need to go into "Settings"->"Advanced"->"Reset Account"  in Metamask for each of the ganache account (which you have imported via private key from Ganache Account into MeteMask)

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling MetaMask on firefox. Sometimes it is just a bit buggy.

Comment: I did .Still seeing same issue with firefox