# Remix pending transaction: Stuck

Tags: solidity, remix

Using `Windows Powershell` as admin I launched `ganache`, changed the environment to `injected web3` inside of Remix and connected to `Localhost 8545` inside of MetaMask.

Ganache starts executing properly and I can see any wallet I swap to on MetaMask via Remix

When I attempt to deploy contract `FowERC20`, Metamask is triggered. When I attempt to execute the transaction a message inside the Remix terminal says `creation of FoWERC20 pending...` and the wallet says `Contract Deployment queued`

Basically, my transactions are stuck. Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Same here, it is annoying! I was deploying smart contracts until, suddenly it stop working.

Comment: Did you try resetting the account's nonce cache in metamask? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/44311/reset-metamask-nonce